# Are 4 wheels optimal for Formula 1 cars?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, friction

My question is whether, for a pre-determined linear speed, 4-wheeled cars have greater mechanical efficiency than cars with $2 n$ wheels where $n \geq 3$. I take it for granted that the car rolls on a flat surface.

I'm not a physicist but here are my arguments for this hypothesis:

1. A four wheel car is more stable than a two wheel or three wheel car.
2. Given that $ F= \mu N$ where $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction and $N$ is the normal force, the area available for contact is unimportant for traction.
3. Whatever advantage additional pairs of wheels might offer would need to off-set the heat lost in additional pairs of wheels and the extra angular momentum required to move those wheels.

Now, let's denote the masses of the first two pairs of wheels as $m_1$ and $m_2$ located at the front and back respectively. Additional pairs of wheels shall be denoted by $m_i$ where $i \geq 3$. For a car with $ 2 n$ wheels and pre-determined mass(700 kg), I argue that:

1. $\forall i \space m_i \geq min(m_1,m_2)$
2. Assuming constant linear speed $v$, the extra angular momentum due to $m_{i \geq 3}$ is approximately:

$ \Delta L=\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} 2 L_i = 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} I_i w_i=  2 v\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} r_i m_i $

where $r_i$ is the radius of each wheel.

3. In a bend/arc that's approximately circular, the extra work done would be approximately:

$\Delta W =\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} 2 W_i = 2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} \frac{m_i v^2}{r} 2 \alpha r=  2 v^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n-2} m_i 2 \alpha $

where $\alpha$ is the angle of the bend, $v$ is the linear speed and $r$ is the radius of the arc.

Extra pairs of wheels might help with improved weight distribution on the axles which might seem useful but this is not an issue for F1 cars which aren't massive. It follows that we would now want to minimise $ \Delta L$ and $ \Delta W$ which is possible when $m_{i \geq 3} = 0$. Note that I've so far said nothing about heat loss as it's not clear to me how this would be modelled.

I suspect that heat loss is a non-linear function of the angular speed of a wheel and varies linearly with the a wheel's width. In fact, I'm particularly interested in hearing how a physicist would model this problem.

Note 1: Once upon a time Formula 1 had six-wheeled cars, the P34. However, as the [following article](https://www.wired.com/2014/12/well-didnt-work-crazy-plan-bring-6-wheeled-cars-f1/) recounts, they didn't do too well.

Note 2: I think my arguments might be incomplete. If so, I'd like to know how they might be improved.

Note 3: I think physics is the right degree of abstraction for this problem as I'm not interested in actually engineering a particular car. Like Carnot, who modelled heat engines, I'm interested in modelling a general class of machines using physics.

Comment: Have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrrell_P34

Comment: And vaguely related, for serious petrol heads only though https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brabham_BT46

Comment: Stability, as with the latest military jets, is a two sides issue. Too stable and vehicles are slow to respond, too unstable means increased response at the price of twitchiness

Comment: I don't actually see a question in here.

Comment: @DavidZ I'm sorry for leaving any ambiguity. My question is whether, for a pre-determined linear speed, 4-wheeled cars have greater mechanical efficiency than cars with $ 2 n$ wheels where $ n \geq 3$.

Comment: OK, the edit helps. Now, you've shown quite a bit of your own work toward figuring this out (which is good). What specific problem did you have that kept you from solving the matter yourself? _That's_ the thing that is unclear. It'd be better if you make your question about that specific issue.

Comment: @DavidZ An important aspect of the problem that isn't very clear to involves modelling heat loss in wheels. I suspect that it's a non-linear function of the angular speed of a wheel and varies linearly with the a wheel's width but I'm not an expert on this matter.

Comment: @DavidZ I just made this clear in the question details.